# trouble getting the last selector using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

im trying to get the attribute "href" from the last selector a but the code doesn't works it doesn't update the url varialbe when i append the data :
JS:

```
jQuery('#displayimagesDiv').scrollExtend(
        {   

            'target': '#displayimagesDiv',          
            'url': $('.nexturl:last').attr('href'),
            'loadingIndicatorEnabled' :  false,
            'loadingIndicatorClass' : 'loading',
            'onSuccess' :{}

        }
);
```

HTML:

```
    @layout('layouts.main')
@section('content')
<fieldset class="meduim_width" id="displayimagesDiv">
<legend><h2>{{ __('general.gallery') }}</h2></legend>
<center>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "********";
/* 4up */
google_ad_slot = "*******";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</center>
<div id="displayimages" style="margin:0;">
@foreach($images->results as $img)
<div class="thumbs">
<a href="{{ URL::to('g/'.AlphaID($img->id)) }}" alt="" title="{{ __('general.show_image') }}" > {{ HTML::image('i/'.AlphaID($img->id)) }} </a>
{{ __('general.views') }} : {{ $img->views }}
</div>
@endforeach 
<a class="nexturl" href="{{URL::current()}}?page={{$images->page+1}}" style="display:none">#</a>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
</fieldset>
<noscript>
 {{ $images->links() }}
 </noscript>

@endsection
```

any help should be good im using Laravel framework and the default template system naming BLADE .

Answer (score 0):

The class .nexturl doesn't exit in your HTML (it is id="nexturl"):

```
...
'url': $('#nexturl').attr('href'),
...
```

Comment: Try with $('#displayimages .nexturl').attr('href') or $('#displayimages .nexturl').last().attr('href')

Comment: sorry , but both methods doesn't works ! it load the same url and not the updating one .

Comment: 1. do a console.log with $('#displayimages .nexturl').last().attr('href') and check if you get the url you're expecting. 2. Hardcode the expectd url into $('#displayimagesDiv').scrollExtend(... and check if the next page is loaded. It might be a bug on the server side.